# CentOS 8, which SVN GUI client can be used on it?

Tags: centos, centos-8

I just installed CentOS 8. I am wondering which SVN client can be used on it?
I am using KDESvn on my years-old Fedora. But now the CentOS 8 is the GNOME desktop.
How about RabbitSvn? it seems that it does not work on some 64bit machines. It requires Python 2 but that is not available on CentOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to KDE, you can still use it on CentOS 8. To install KDE:

```
dnf --enablerepo=epel,PowerTools group -y install "KDE Plasma Workspaces" "base-x"
echo "exec /usr/bin/startkde" >> ~/.xinitrc
startx
```

For more information see the article
[How to Install the KDE Plasma Desktop on CentOS 8](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-kde-plasma-centos/).

Otherwise, the safest SVN interface is via the browser, which does not depend on the
operating system version. Depending on the SVN server, you would access it via
a URL such as `https://dlp.srv.world/project/`.
You could perhaps also use the package
[RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/)
which integrates into nautilus.